# Displaying cropped faces with react

Tags: reactjs, image-processing

I'm trying to make a deepfake detection website .
I'm cropping the faces from the image using viola-jones algorithm.
when i upload an image to the website and get a response back from the backend I'm getting an array of length equal to the number of faces in the image

[image: thats how my array looks like (2 faces in this case)]

[image]
my question is how can i convert these arrays back to images representing each face and display them on my website?

i have a state called faces

```
  const [face, setFace] = useState([]);
```

and i'm putting the faces from the response in it

```
      setFace(response.data.faces);
```

I don't know what the next step is can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like:

```
<image src={`data:image/png;base64,${base64ByteArray}`}/>
```

Just make sure that a byte array is converted correctly into a string representation.